# PHP loop functions till it finds file

Tags: php

I have following functions:

```
//Check if file exists
function check_if_file_exists($row,$last_query_id){         
    $excerpt  = $row -> excerpt;
    $filename = '/' . $excerpt . '.jpg';
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        return $row;
    } else {
        single_query_for_replacement_value($last_query_id);                                 
    }                   
};

//New query search for the replacement value in case there is no image
function single_query_for_replacement_value($last_query_id){                        
    $query    = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ID < '$last_query_id' order by ID desc limit 1";    
    $results  = mysql_query($query);
    $row      = $results[0]; //first and only result
    $new_id   = $row -> ID;     
    check_if_file_exists($row,$new_id);                 
};
```

The idea is that the first functions checks for each "excerpt" from query to see if file exists or not.

If it exists, then it simply returns the value.

If not, it gets another value using the second function.

However this new value also needs to be checked if the file exists before being returned.

You will notice that the second function does not have `return` but rather calls the first function again to check for the file.

The idea was that both functions will loop through till it finds a data with file.

The new value does not get returned. I am not sure if it is even correct.

Could someone give me a feedback on how to loop through functions and only return if file exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
function check_if_file_exists($row,$last_query_id){         
        $excerpt  = $row -> excerpt;
        $filename = '/' . $excerpt . '.jpg';
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
            return $row;
        } else {
            $query    = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ID < '$last_query_id' order by ID desc limit 1";    
            $results  = mysql_query($query);
            $row      = $results[0]; //first and only result
            $new_id   = $row -> ID;
            return check_if_file_exists($row,$new_id);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
function single_query_for_replacement_value($last_query_id){
```

to

```
function single_query_for_replacement_value($last_query_id,$offset){
```

and

```
    $query    = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ID < '$last_query_id' order by ID desc limit 1";
```

to

```
    $query    = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ID < '$last_query_id' order by ID desc limit 1, " . $offset;
```

and

```
    single_query_for_replacement_value($last_query_id);
```

to

```
    single_query_for_replacement_value($last_query_id,$offset++);
```

and just remove `WHERE ID < '$last_query_id'` from your query. Initialise offset to 0.

The idea is to iterate over your entire resultset 1 result at a time by using `LIMIT 1` and `OFFSET 1` until we find what you are looking for.